# I'm creating an ASP.NET website for selling furniture and I am confused about creating my database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, .nettiers

[My Asp template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5UlX.png)

I'm creating my first ASP.NET website for selling furniture and I am confused about creating my database. I want to sell products for many categories like bedrooms, and every user can add products to cart; here is my master page template

Comment: Link to "My Asp template" does not work.

Comment: You can instead an image right into Stackoverflow using SO editor

Comment: http://www.nopcommerce.com/

Comment: You are getting mark downs because your question is too general. Stackoverflow users and Stackoverflow rules expect a specific question. People on this forum want you to try and do it yourself before asking questions. 

This is challenging though if you do not know where to start and haven't had much training/experience with what you are trying to do.

You will have to live with the mark downs to your question, I think Stackoverflow should allow beginners to ask "broad" questions like this because you just got a great answer from @Siyavash that should greatly help you get direction.

Answer (score 1):

I introduce you a ***simple database*** design for the issue using 4 proposed tables in the following:

1. **Persons**; to keep your users info in it.
2. **ProductCategories**; to keep the product groups in it as mentioned like bedroom.
3. **Products**; to keep the all products with their categories.
4. **Carts**; actually this is not mandatory, you can manage this by cookies.

Note: This proposal is very very basic and simple, so it can be extended by your needs.

---

Here is the mentioned tables with their fields(in the minimum) as graphical interface in the ***Microsoft SQL Server*** design:
[image: Proposed furniture database, very simple design.]